# Combine multiple images and display it in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, image-processing

I am a beginner in OpenCV and Qt, my project now is combining multiple images and display it on Qt Creator.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
string img_path = "/home/m/pictures/cat.jpg";
std::vector<cv::Mat> img_pool;
for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    cv::Mat data = cv::imread(img_path,-1);
    img_pool.push_back(data);
}
    cv::Mat data = cv::imread(img_path,-1);
cv::namedWindow("image", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
cv::imshow("image",data);
cv::waitKey(0);
cv::Mat data_dst = cv::Mat::zeros(500, 500, data.type());
cv::Mat data_resize;


for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        cv::resize( img_pool[3], data_resize, cv::Size(50,50));
        cv::Rect f_target(i*50,j*50,50,50);
        data_resize.copyTo(data_dst(f_target));
    }
}
cv::namedWindow("image_n", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
cv::imshow("image_n",data_dst);
cv::waitKey(0);
return 0;
}
```

Here is the result:

[image: my code result]

My code now can display one image but what I want to do is display different multiple images, I think I need to load the images or image path to the vector but I failed, so someone can help me?

Comment: There is no Qt used in your code. Also - in what way do you want to display multiple images? At once in a grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Qt used in your code. If you want something like this with Qt, you can use a simple widget with a grid layout or a flowlayout. Then load all the images from a path in an array of QImage and the display it.

You can find an example with [FlowLayout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html) here. You can use a QLabel to display the image, convert your QImage to QPixmap and the use:

```
 QImage yourImage("path");
 QLabel image new QLabel(centralwidget);
 imagelabel->setGeometry(QRect(20, 10, 371, 311));
 imagelabel->setPixmap(QPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(yourImage));
```

If you are new with Qt, you can integrate it easily with QML using a FlowLayout and and array of QML components. Look this example of the usage of an [ImageViewer](http://qt.apidoc.info/5.1.1/qtquickcontrols/gallery-content-imageviewer-qml.html)

Comment: Sorry, I am using Qt but for this project I only use OpenCV to combine different multiple images first and then write to a location after that I create a textlabel to show it.